# matching query does not exist. DoesNotExist at /blog/postComment

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-apps

I am trying to add the feature of commenting and replying to it in my blog. But it is constantly throwing me the error of "BlogComment matching query does not exist."

```
def postComment(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        user = request.user
        postSno = request.POST.get('postSno')
        post = Post.objects.get(sno=postSno)
        parentSno = request.POST.get('parentSno')
        if parentSno == "":
            comment = BlogComment(comment=comment, user=user, post=post)
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your comment has been posted successfully")
        else:
            parent = BlogComment.objects.get(sno=parentSno)
            comment = BlogComment(comment=comment, user=user, post=post, parent=parent)
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your reply has been posted successfully")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` method returns `None` by default when the specified key does not exist.

So you should check `if parentSno is not None:` instead of `if parentSno == "":`.

(alternately, you could also change that default value by using the second argument of the `get()` method: `parentSno = request.POST.get('parentSno', "")` ([see here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) for example)).

Comment: Damn, thank you so much. It worked. I am new to Django hence got confused.Thanks again

Comment: @SantanuKumar You're welcome! Could you mark the question as solved?